# Why is df.reset_index() adding 5 zeros after a decimal in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am an MPH Epidemiology student in a data science introduction class with just about NO programming experience. I have uploaded a json file into pycharm, converted it to a dataframe using

```
pub_num = pd.DataFrame(papers['Publication_Year'].value_counts())
```

Then reset the index using

```
pub_num = pub_num.reset_index()
```

After resetting the index, it took the whole numbers that were in my dataframe and added 5 zeros after a decimal point.  Now i'm trying to plot the dataframe, and I can't plot them correctly bc it's not recognizing whole numbers.

Why is it adding zeroes and how do I get rid of them?  It is showing up fine in my console.  No zeros.  But then I look in the environment and 'view as dataframe' in the bottom right corner, I can see all the zeroes.  [screen shot showing the console with no zeroes and the dataframe with zeroes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKz7D.jpg)

I've tried changing back to int using df.astype(int) and changing the precision to 0.  But neither have worked.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# open and prints out the json file
with open('Papers.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# convert to pandas dataframe.
papers = pd.read_json('Papers.json')

# creates a dataframe to count the number of publications in each year
pub_num = pd.DataFrame(papers['Publication_Year'].value_counts())
pub_num = pub_num.reset_index()
pub_num.columns = ['Publication_Year', 'Counts']
print(pub_num)
```

The output of the df is:

```
       Publication_Year  Counts
0              2010      10
1              2009       5
```

my code for the plot is this:

```
plt.scatter(x = 'Publication_Year', y = 'Counts', data = pub_num)
plt.xlabel('Publication Year')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.show()
```

[Plot using the plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPII5.jpg)

[plot if I don't use plt.ticklable_format function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j02s1.jpg)

UPDATE:
So I took the suggestion of transforming to date time using:

```
pub_num['Publication_Year'] = pd.to_datetime(pub_num['Publication_Year'],format='%Y')
```

This is the graph that came out:
[Graph using the conversion to years instead of integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItfMC.jpg) 
It's still adding extra numbers after year, which is why I honestly believe it because there are zeroes after my decimals in my df as shown in the first picture.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you do: df.astype(object).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: I get an error:ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: I just tried copy/past the whole trace back error and it says too long.  Is there another way to post it?

Comment: Adding zeroes after the decimal point should give you no problem in plotting these results. Can you elaborate on why you can't plot your data?

Comment: @rafaelc, I wish I can upload another picture.  So instead of my x axis plotting 2001, 2002, 2003.... 2010.  It's looks like 2009.2, 2009.4, 2009.6, 2009.8....etc. And that's after I did plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False) to turn off the scientific notation it was putting it in or something similar.  I'm trying to make a scatter plot with a trend line.  The x is years, the y is the count of articles for each year from the original dataframe. Which i pulled from a webscraper using biopython from pubmed, which is a whole nother mess.  I can only pull 15 records :-(

Comment: maybe provide some data sample, and more precise information concerning your environement : python version, module versions, notebook/python console tool and so on. Also, what do you want to plot, how, and the error name and last 5  relevant lines of the call stack. You can also upload picutres (for your diagrams, otherwise, provide text).

Comment: @pandora You're falling into a XY Problem. You believe the problem lies on "adding zeroes" after the decimal point, but apparently it's got nothing to do with it. Assume everything is correct with your `df` and explain the question that really matters: why is your plotting outputting `2009.2`, `2009.4`, ... instead of `2001`, `2002` etc? You should add some sample data and preferably a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your problem and spot the error, Usually though, with the relevante lines of code provided and some data, it's easy to spot the problem by just reading

Comment: @LoneWanderer Sure thing.  Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32.  I'm using pycharm as stated above. It has a console and a debug in it so I can watch the variables change line by line, which is how i know it happened after using the reset_index line.  I can't upload pictures in the comments.  Do I edit the original post? I'm not getting an error, but the plot showing the zeroes on the x axis instead of keeping it as whole integers.  I don't want 2009.2 years, I want 2009.  Am I explaining this ok?

Comment: @rafaelc Ok, i read your suggestion.  I'll try. I post it in the original question then as an edit, i'm assuming?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes! Sounds great. Just edit and add only the plot parts (i.e. plt.plot(...) and related code) and the image that is output from the code. :}

Comment: In addition, pandas has a feature for converting data to date/time, which should be the preferred way to deal with dates. I think seaborn and matplotlib deal with this quite nicely. It helps interpreting time daat such years as float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has **nothing** to do with zeroes in your data frame.

In your first output, you have only two rows.

```
       Publication_Year  Counts
0              2010          10
1              2009           5
```

In plotting terms, you'll have two ordered pairs : (2009, 5) and (2010, 10). This means you'll have two points in your graph.

That's *exactly* what's being outputted [in this link you provided.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPII5.jpg) Since `2010` and `2009` are integers, pandas will just interpolate values in the `xticks` on the `x` axis for readability. These values don't mean anything, they are just part of the `x` axis, but you can totally modify them by messing with the `xticks` and `xtickslabels` arguments of the `plt.plot` function.

When you make your values `datetime`, your data will look something like this:

```
     Publication_Year  Counts
0          2010-01-01      10
1          2009-01-01       5
```

Again, you'll have two points in your data frame. Pandas will, again, interpolate in between these points for readability. Since the beginning is `January 2009` and the end is `January 2010`, you'll have `March`, `April`, `July` etc in between *just for readability*.

Again, this has **nothing to do with decimal points**.

If you add `plt.xticks([2009, 2010])` just before your `plt.show()` line, you'll enforce your code to have just two ticks: 2009 and 2010. The result would be something like:

[image]

Comment: YOUR ARE A LIFE SAVER!  THANK YOU so much for pointing me in the right direction.  my thought process was way off.  So the whole thing was just an automation by the module?  Eventually, the dataframe should have about 500 rows instead of 15 so i'll hopefully have more than just the 2 data points.  I'm assuming as I get more data points and it spreads out a bit, I don't have to worry about manually doing the ticks?   I found https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html & https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm

Comment: @pandora Exactly! Once you have 500 rows, it's very likely that you won't need to worry about the ticks. Of course you can always manipulate them using the `xticks` method (along with `np.arange` to automatically generate ticks for you with steps, for example), but rarely that's necessary. Glad I could help!